# Multiple subscriptions in iron router

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I have been working on an application using a comment function. That results in having to subscribe to both a collection which the comments are made on and the comments collection itself. Now it looks like this:

> `<template name="bookView">
>   {{> book}}
>   {{> comments}}
>   </template>`

```
this.route('book', {
    path: '/book/:_id',
    template: 'bookView',
    waitOn: function() { return Meteor.subscribe('book');},
    action: function () {
        if (this.ready()){
            this.render();
        }
        else
            this.render('loadingTemplate');
    },
    data: function() {return Books.findOne(this.params._id);}
});
```

But now I would like to load all comments belonging to that book also. Or should I handle the subscription of comments in Template.comments.rendered?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yeah you have two ways:

Logic in Controller. You can subscribe with an array to multiple collections. This would be the way you go when you show all the comments instantly.

```
    this.route('book', {
      path: '/book/:_id',
      template: 'bookView',
      /* just subscribe to the book you really need, change your publications */
      waitOn: function() {
        return [Meteor.subscribe('book', this.params._id),
               Meteor.subscribe('comments', this.params._id)];
      },
      data: function() {
        return {
        book : Books.findOne(this.params._id),
        comments: Comments.find(this.params._id)}
      }
    });
```

If you dont want to show comments until they are requested by the user. You can follow another way:

You can set the `bookId` on `buttonclick` into a Session variable. Than you can define a Deps.autorun function which subscribes to the comments collection with the `bookId` provided in your Session variable. In your comments template you just have to do the normal collection request. If you need more hints about this way let me know.

Comment: I have the same issue and some problems with Data being parsed and rendered withe the meteor 0.8 renderer before it is at the client.
How can I check if the subscriptions were successful?

Comment: The waitOn-function always waits until the data is received. So your subsciption should always succeed.

Comment: How to access book data from tempalate events ?

Answer (score 5):

Your waitOn function can wait for multiple subscriptions by returning an array of the subscription handles.