# Subscribe several collections with conditional &&

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

Why the follow code works in Iron router, when I'm subscribing several collections at the same time, Im returning `Collection1&&Collection2 etc` [view code].

I read this question [Multiple subscriptions in iron router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22940628/multiple-subscriptions-in-iron-router) where he is suggesting to add several subscriber via an `array`, I'm doing different just cause is working and I found was working after try and error. But to be honest I don't know why is working. Can someone explain why conditions works to return all the collections?.

```
Meteor.startup(function(){
    Router.route('/',
        {
            name : "dashboard",
            waitOn : function(){

                if(!Meteor.loggingIn() && !Meteor.user()) {
                    this.redirect("login");
                }

                return Meteor.subscribe("collection_1") &&
                    Meteor.subscribe("collection_2") &&
                    Meteor.subscribe("collection_3") &&
                    Meteor.subscribe("collection_4");
            },

            onBeforeAction : function(){
                if(!Meteor.loggingIn() && !Meteor.user()) {
                    this.redirect("login");
                }

                this.next();
            },

            action : function(){
                this.render();
            }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning multiple subscriptions with && should work because `Meteor.subscribe('subscription')` will always return an object with a subscription ID, and `onReady` / `onStop` callbacks, even if you subscribe to something that does not exists. But if the subscription does not exists the `onReady` callback won't be called.

So, the return statement will evaluate each objects as "true" and go through all the statements to launch all the subscriptions.